# Kendo UI Treeview - Binding with Hierarchical data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview, kendo-datasource

Sorry for asking basic question, I am using Kendo UI first time.

My question is:

I have hierarchical data returned from SQL Server Common Type Expression (CTE) in below format

Id                  ParentId               Name

1   0   Name-1 (Level 0)

2   0   Name-2 (Level 0)

3   1   Name-3 (Level 1)

4   3   Name-4 (Level 2)

and so on...

I need to bind this data to Kendo UI Tree View control. All the samples I saw in Kendo UI docs deals with hard coded data and then there is HierachicalDataSoruce examples but in those examples hierarchical Json object is manually created (using a movie example). I am sure there would be some way to bind Kendo UI controls (tree view or grid) with hierarchical data directly, just I am not getting it.

If anyone comes across similar situation or know something then please let me know how to deal with this situation.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to provide the data in a format supported by Kendo's DataSource, e.g. a JavaScript array; in case of a treeview, each object in the array will (at minimum) need to have a property containing the text to display (`item.text` by default) and a property which contains an array of child nodes (`item.items` by default).

You can either transform your data on the server-side, or on the client-side, but ultimately, you'll have to define how to interpret your data somewhere so the treeview widget can render it.

You can [remap some of those fields](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/web/treeview/overview#item-definition) using the Kendo TreeView configuration, e.g. the text field:

```
$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
  dataTextField: "Name",
  dataSource: items
});
```

For others, you can [use the schema model](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/web/treeview/overview#projecting-the-treeview-state) of your data source configuration (also see [Model.define](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/model#methods-Model.define)), or if you need additional logic to map your existing item properties, you can use [schema.parse](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-schema.parse).