# Kendo ui MVC treeview from sql server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

If I have the below table in SQL Server. Is there a way for me to load it into a Kendo ui MVC treeview? All the demos on their site have static tree nodes. I attempted, but it somehow does doesn't group things together.

Id          Name                                               ParentId

1           USA                                                NULL

2           Texas                                              1

3           Houston                                            2

4           Katy                                               3

5           Spring                                             3

6           Florida                                            1

7          Tallahassee                                         6

8           Massachusetts                                      1

9           Boston                                             8

10          Springfield                                        9

Here's my attempt to populated the tree:
Controller:

```
var modelsList = new List<TreeModel>();
        var connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"];

        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString.ToString()))
        using (var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Id, Name, ParentId FROM tblTree ", conn))
        {                               
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                int id2 = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Id"]);
                string attributeName = reader["AttributeName"].ToString();
                var parentId = reader["ParentId"];
                var model = new TreeModel();
                model.Id = id2;
                model.Name = attributeName;
                if (parentId != DBNull.Value)
                    model.hasChildren = Convert.ToInt32(parentId);
                else
                    model.hasChildren = 0;

                modelsList.Add(model);
            }

        }

        return Json(modelsList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to convert your list into a hierarchical data structure, so that each node has an array of child nodes (the tree view will inspect `model.items` by default, but you can [customize the field name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20849913/2001735)). [Here's a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945216/converting-flattened-hierarchical-data-from-sql-server-into-a-structured-json-ob/6945446#6945446) on how you might do that on the server-side. Unfortunately, there currently is no way to specify a parent id field which would automate this for you (although I'd suggest raising this issue in the [feedback forum](http://feedback.kendoui.com/forums/127393-kendo-ui-feedback), since the question has come up a number of times now).